# Custom output format serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework, and I have this serializer.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.CharField()
    phone = serializers.CharField()
```

That produces something like this:

```
[
    {"name": "NAME", "email": "EMAIL", "phone": "PHONE"},
    {"name": "NAME", "email": "EMAIL", "phone": "PHONE"},
    {"name": "NAME", "email": "EMAIL", "phone": "PHONE"},
]
```

But I want the response to look this way:

```
{
  "new_user": ID_NEW_USER,
  "data": [
    {"name": "NAME", "email": "EMAIL", "phone": "PHONE"},
    {"name": "NAME", "email": "EMAIL", "phone": "PHONE"},
    {"name": "NAME", "email": "EMAIL", "phone": "PHONE"},
  ]
}
```

So I'm doing this. But it looks like I should be using another serializer.

```
class UserListView(CustomClassMixin):
    def get(self, request):
        users = Users.objects.all()
        new_user = QUERY_TO_GET_NEW_USER
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)

        return Response({"new_user": new_user, "data": serializer.data})
```

I have tried using the method to_representation but seems that it might be an easier way.

Anyone knows the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    new_user = serializers.IntegerField()
    data = serializers.ListSerializer(child=UserSerializer)  # eventually UserSerializer(many=True)
```

But this do not change much, as Serializer initialization will be almost the same as your current Response.

However, you can take a look at Pagination classes - because I think this is the piece that you are missing.

So, in the `rest_framework.pagination` you can find different types of pagination,  let's focus on: PageNumberPagination, there is a method there:

```
def get_paginated_response(self, data):
    return Response(OrderedDict([
        ('count', self.count),
        ('next', self.get_next_link()),
        ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
        ('results', data)
    ]))
```

Now you can simply modify it to fulfill your needs; so change `results` to `data` and add additional field for `new_user`.

Also - wonder why you do not using ModelViewSets. Anyway - if you have any question - please ask. Happy coding.